# List is not displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two pages one is new.html and other is lead.html.So, when i clicked on submit button in new.html ,the record fields should be added to the list in lead.html.
Here is my code.
new.html

```
 //form validation

 function validateForm() {
var x = document.forms["myForm"]["name"].value;
var y= document.forms["myForm"]["strtd"].value;
var z= document.forms["myForm"]["sub"].value;

if (x==null || x=="") {
    alert("Record name must be filled out");
    return false;
}

       else if (y==null || y=="") {
    alert("Started Date must be filled out");
    return false;
      }

    else if (z==null || z=="") {
    alert("Submitted Date must be filled out");
    return false;
        }
           else {

     alert("New Record Created");


  var listCreated = false;


   //Create the listview if not created
    if(!listCreated){
     $("$.content").append("<ul id='list' data-role='listview' data-inset='true' >       </ul>");
    listCreated = true;
     $("$.content").trigger("create");
      }
      var value = $("$.label1").val();
            $("#list").append("<li>" + value +" </li>");
            $("#list").listview("refresh");
      var value = $("$.label2").val();
            $("#list").append("<li>" + value +" </li>");
            $("#list").listview("refresh");
      var value = $("$.label3").val();
            $("#list").append("<li>" + value +" </li>");
            $("#list").listview("refresh");

            }


           }
       </script>

         </head>

         <body>
        <form name="myForm"  type="get" onsubmit="return validateForm()"             action="lead.html">
       <div id="top"> New Record</div>

       <div>

        <h5>Record Name <input type="text" name="RecordName" id="name"></h5>

        </div>
        <div >
       <h5>Started Date <input id="strtd" type="text" name="StartedDate"></h5>
       </div>
        <div>
        <h5>Submitted Date <input id="sub" type="text" name="SubmitedDate"></h5>
      </div><br>
       <div align="center">
       <input  type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" >
      </div>
      </form>
        <div align="center">
       <button id="cancel" onclick="back()">Back</button>
       </div>
      </body>
```

and my lead.html

```
    <body id="lead">
   <div id="top" align="center" > Leads </div>
    <img  id="back" src="./images/back_icon@2x.png" onclick="onBackKey()" >
     <div>
     <div data-role="page"   style="margin-top:100px;" >
      <div data-role="main" id="content">
         <label id="label1"  > </label><br>
        <label id="label2"></label><br>
          <label id="label3"></label>
        <img  id="arrow" src="./images/Arrow@2x.png" style="margin-left:250px" onclick="mylead1()">
     </div>
   </div> 
   </div>

  </body>
```

Please help me in getting listview in lead.html.

Comment: `$("$.content")`? Shouldn't that be `$("#content")`?

Comment: Try reading up on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494984/pass-parameters-between-two-pages-in-two-different-files-in-jquery-mobile

Comment: RGragam..you are right .My question is "How  we can use the id  which is in other page?"(either this #xxx or this $.xxx).