# Pass parameter between pages using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, local-storage

What is the right way to pass parameters between pages in jquery mobile. In Q&A of jquery mobile, there is some suggestion for plugin. Is it mandatory? Please let me know the correct way. There is no one concrete answer. I have to pass parameters for all links in my page.

http://view.jquerymobile.com/master/demos/faq/pass-query-params-to-page.php

Comment: See also this answer to a similar question:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35259962/3209859

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Data/Parameters manipulation between page transitions

It is possible to send a parameter/s from one page to another during page transition. It can be done in few ways.

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13932240/1848600

**Solution 1:**

You can pass values with changePage:

```
$.mobile.changePage('page2.html', { dataUrl : "page2.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : true, changeHash : true });
```

And read them like this:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index", function (event, data) {
    var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
    parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
    alert(parameter);
});
```

#### [Example][3]:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#index",function () {
            $(document).on('click', "#changePage",function () {     
                $.mobile.changePage('second.html', { dataUrl : "second.html?paremeter=123", data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, reloadPage : false, changeHash : true });
            }); 
        }); 

        $(document).on('pagebeforeshow', "#second",function () {
            var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
            parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
            alert(parameter);
        });         
    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="index">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                First Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
          <a data-role="button" id="changePage">Test</a>
        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

**second.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="widdiv=device-widdiv, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://www.dragan-gaic.info/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js">
    </script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>  
   </head>
   <body>
    <!-- Home -->
    <div data-role="page" id="second">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>
                Second Page
            </h3>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">

        </div> <!--content-->
    </div><!--page-->

  </body>
</html>
```

**Solution 2:**

Or you can create a persistent javascript object for a storage purpose. As long ajax is used for page loading (and page is not reloaded in any way) that object will stay active.

```
var storeObject = {
    firstname : '',
    lastname : ''
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/9KKbx/

**Solution 3:**

You can also access data from the previous page like this:

```
$('#index').live('pagebeforeshow', function (e, data) {
    alert(data.prevPage.attr('id'));
});
```

**prevPage** object holds a complete previous page.

**Solution 4:**

As a last solution we have a nifty HTML implementation of localStorage. It only works with HTML5 browsers (including Android and iOS browsers) but all stored data is persistent through page refresh.

```
if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
    localStorage.firstname="Dragan";
    localStorage.lastname="Gaic";            
}
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/J9NTr/

## More info

If you want to learn more about this topic take a look at this [**article**](http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/). You will find several solutions with examples.

Comment: Thanks Gajotres. There are so many ways to do the same thing. But, which is the standard recommended way. My simple example, I have a list of news articles. When some news article is tapped, i want to pass the corresponding news article id to the server so that it opens the news details page. Can you please show this in an example. Say, i have a <div class="news"> News Listing </div> -News Listing here refers to list of items.

Comment: That is something different. My solutions are made to work without server support. Solution 1 would work in your case but that is not a standard way. Correct way would be to use a ajax, connect to server, pull new page data and show it in another page. Here's a working example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15205437/jquery-mobile-how-to-correctly-submit-form-data/15205612#15205612

Comment: Incase if i have passed a parameter to a page, and retrieved using the data-url attribute, it works fine. But, if i refresh that page, the url parameter will not be available. What should be done for this.

Comment: Gajotres - Can you pls clarify the above question.

Comment: @user694688 I created a [plug-in](https://github.com/CameronAskew/jquery.mobile.paramsHandler) which preserves the variables in the actual URL string so refreshes and going going directly to a page work fine.

Comment: Why read the passed parameter from the page that's sending it? Shouldn't the new page read the parameter that's been passed from a previous one?

Answer (score 3):

You can also use it with external relations in links (for me and my purpose its easier), so I wanted to share this:

HTML:

```
 <a href="page1.htm?structure='123'">Structure</a>
```

JS:

```
$( document ).on( "pageinit", "#page1", function( event ) {
  var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];
  parameter = parameters.replace("structure=","");
  alert(parameter);
});
```

In my case, the structure='123' is created dynamically, nobody writes a fixed value '123' for dynamic purposes :-)

Thanks for the URL-splitting of the above post (pls. favor his post), this is just an addition / further explanation.

Comment: in my case, i need to load link with id like this `<a href="#page1?structure='123'">Structure</a>` and its not worked for splitting.