# How to send parameter using $.mobile.navigate to pagebeforeshow under different closure

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

Hi in my application i am navigating from one div to another div using the below code,

```
$.mobile.navigate( "#formsEnterId", { info: "info about the #formsEnterIdhash" });

$("#formsEnterId").on('pagebeforeshow', function (event, data) {
            console.log("Entered page before show::",data);    //How to fetch the info here??
        });
```

In the pagebeforeshow event i want to fetch the info attribute.I don't know how to fetch 
the info attribute.But the page navigation is successful.

Also i used $.mobile.changepage but no luck.

Please someone assist me to get the info attribute in pagebeforeShow event.
I already saw the related answers posted in [Pass parameter between pages using jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518912/pass-parameter-between-pages-using-jquery-mobile)

But that doesn't solve my problem because my page navigate script and pagebeforeshow event are under different closures.

Comment: Which JQM version are you using?

Comment: @Omar thank you for your reply.I am using JQM 1.3.2

Answer (score 0):

As everything is loaded into the DOM we can create a global object for data storing.

live example : http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/9KKbx/

```
var storeObject = {
    parameter1: null,
    parameter2 : null
}
// Store object
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(e, data){    
    alert("My name is " + data.prevPage.find('#test-input').val());
});
```

Another way is storing variable in local storage

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){      
    $(document).on('click', '#change-page-button', function(){    
        // store some data
        if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined") {
              localStorage.firstname="Dragan";
              localStorage.lastname="Gaic";           
        }
        // Change page
        $.mobile.changePage("#second");
    });   
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#second', function(){      
    alert('My name is ' + localStorage.firstname + ' ' + localStorage.lastname);
    // Lets change localStorage data before we go to the next page
    localStorage.firstname="NewFirstNeme";
    localStorage.lastname="NewLastName";   
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#third', function(){      
    alert('My name is ' + localStorage.firstname + ' ' + localStorage.lastname);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply.I am following your 1st approach.Here "storeObject" is a global variable??Also i don't understand find('#test-input') why we need this??

Comment: see the example http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/9KKbx/

Comment: It's nice to see people are still using my stuff :)