# Jquery mobile - how to retrieve the data passed from one.html in two.html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I followed this link:

[Pass parameter between pages using jquery mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16518912/pass-parameter-between-pages-using-jquery-mobile)

But all it is doing is

```
 1) pass a parameter to a new HTML page(one.html->two.html)
 2) Read what's been passed from one.html in one.html before page disappears.
 - but i want to read the data in two.html, not in one.html
```

Isn't it? I maybe wrong. But that's what the code seems to be doing.

in one.html, i'm passing the data to two.html like this:

```
$( document ).delegate("#page1", "pageinit", function() {

    $.mobile.changePage('two.html', { 
        dataUrl : "two.html?paremeter=123", 
        data : { 'paremeter' : '123' }, 
        reloadPage : true, changeHash : true
    });

});
```

How to I retrieve this data from two.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in two.html

```
$(document).on('pageshow', "#twoIndex", function (event, data) {
    var parameters = $(this).data("url").split("?")[1];;
    parameter = parameters.replace("parameter=","");  
    alert(parameter);
});
```

consider using localStorage and sessionStorage.
for more have look at [gajotres's blog post.](http://www.gajotres.net/passing-data-between-jquery-mobile-pages/)